# SQL Server 2008 R2 query

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm running the following query, but it is taking too long. Is there a way to make it faster or change the way the query is written?

Please help.

```
SELECT *
FROM   ProductGroupLocUpdate WITH (nolock)
WHERE  CmStatusFlag > 2
       AND EngineID IN ( 0, 1 )
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT DISTINCT APGV.LocationID
                       FROM CM_ST_ActiveProductGroupsView AS APGV WITH(nolock)
                       WHERE APGV.LocationID = ProductGroupLocUpdate.Locationid);
```

Comment: You can get rid of the distinct in the inner query, though SQL server will probably figure this out for itself. Short of that what are your table definitions? what indexes do you have? How many rows do your tables have?

Comment: You're not giving us a lot to go on..... (1) what do the tables involved in that query look like (structure)? (2) what kind of data do they contain - how many rows, how selective are the columms? (3) what kind of indexing do you already have in place?

Answer (score 0):

Try rewriting the query with a join

```
SELECT PGLU.* from ProductGroupLocUpdate PGLU WITH (NOLOCK) 
LEFT JOIN CM_ST_ActiveProductGroupsView APGV WITH (NOLOCK) 
        ON PGLU.LocationId = APGV.LocationID
WHERE APGV.LocationID IS NULL AND CmStatusFlag>2 AND EngineID IN (0,1)
```

Depending on how much data is in your table, check add indexes to LocationId (in both tables), CmStatusFlag and EngineID

Comment: The left join table is a view

Comment: @faiz: The fact that the LEFT JOIN table is a view is the engine's problem, not the person writing the SQL.  However, since you've not shown the definition of the view, it is quite possible that the correlated sub-query you're currently executing is exacerbating the problem of working with a view, and is a major contribution to the overall performance problem.